# how to access mouse coordinates in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and I am working on my first real game. I'm having trouble with getting and storing mouse coordinates. Basically, whenever the screen is touched, I need to do something based on where it is clicked. Below is my code.

public class NonmultiplierSixGame extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyView(this));

}


public class MyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{
    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View MyView, MotionEvent event) {
        Globals.SetSelect(-2);
        float mx = event.getX();
        float my = event.getY();

        if (mx > 10 && my > 10) {
            Globals.SetSelect(1);
        }
        else {
            Globals.SetSelect(0);
        }
        return true;

    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //I have a bunch of shapes and text here
        }
    }
```

select is a public static int being stored in a `Globals.java` file and is initially set to -1. When I run the code, the value of select is not changed when I click anywhere.
 I tried to search for an answer but I couldn't find anything, so I decided to get a stack overflow account and ask a question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) maybe helpful and you can get the  mouse coordinates in `MyView` like this:

```
public class MyView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

EDIT :

Reading documents [Layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) and [TouchEvent](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch.html) will be helpful. You should put your `MyView` into a layout, here is my code and it works fine:

HomeActivity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

activity_main:

```
  <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.myapplication.MyView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyView :

```
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e("TAG","==================  TouchEvent");

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //I have a bunch of shapes and text here
}
```

Comment: I replaced the OnClick function with the following code:                     public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        float mx = event.getX();
        float my = event.getY();

        if (mx > 10 && my > 10) {
            Globals.SetSelect(1);
        }
        else {
            Globals.SetSelect(0);
        }
        return true;
    }                                                                                                                   However it still does not work. Do I need to have it split into cases based on which event is used as above?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. When I run the above code it still does not work however. In the editer, when I move my cursor over onTouchEvent it says: "method 'onTouchEvent(android.view.View, android.view.MotionEvent)' is never used". Is this part of the problem? Thanks again, I really appreciate the help :)

Comment: You should write OnTouchEvent in MyView .

Comment: My project still isn't doing anything when I click on it. I updated my code in the original post. I spent the last week trying to figure it out but I can't get it to do anything :(

Comment: @mathexplorer I have update my answer and it works fine.